No puedo obtener los datos de mi base de datos de firebase para mostrarlos en android studio
Recientemente he intentado obtener un dato específico que está dentro de otros nodos para mostrarlo en mi app en android studio. El detalle es que no parece que no se conecta al servidor y no obtiene los datos necesarios.
Este es el código que utilicé:
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user == null) {
        // No user is signed in
        // You may want to handle this case
    } else {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UsersData").child(user.getUid()).child("readings");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Map<String, Float> monthVolumes = new HashMap<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String timeStamp = snapshot.child("timestamp").getValue(String.class);
                        float volume = snapshot.child("volume_L").getValue(Float.class);
                        try {
                            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).parse(timeStamp);
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.setTime(date);
                            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            String monthName = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault()).getMonths()[month];
                            if (monthVolumes.containsKey(monthName)) {
                                monthVolumes.put(monthName, monthVolumes.get(monthName) + volume);
                            } else {
                                monthVolumes.put(monthName, volume);
                            }
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    setupBarChart(monthVolumes);
                }
            }

Y esta es la estructura de la base de datos:

Qué podría estar sucediendo?
